# Is there another way to say 'working on'?

Tags: phrases, phrasing

Is there another way to say "We are working on to update our resort."? I do not want to use *working on*.

Comment: If you let us know why you don't want to use "working on"--what sense it adds to or omits from what you want to say--we will be able to help you better.

Comment: I prefer not to use it as it may imply that we are under construction works and may affect our business

Comment: So... what exactly /are/ you doing?

Comment: The example is ungrammatical (it should be *""We are working on **updating** our resort""*). But as StoneyB says - why would you want to change the specific words "working on"? I suspect very likely "resort" isn't the right word here, but we can't say much unless you tell us what you actually *mean*.

Comment: ""We are working on updating our resort"" sounds good. I did not want to use "working on" in the sentense as we are responding to a question about our hotel and we dont want to make it sound as we are under construction works but only making some decor enhancements and furnitures updates

Answer (score 3):

I would think any kind of phrase implying ***current*** updating, improvements, modernization, would be interpreted by travelers as ***"under construction"***, much like ***"cozy starter home"*** usually means cramped, 1-bath converted garage or other too-small structure.  :-)

If you want to avoid the implication of being "under construction", you can use a more ambiguous phrase such as:

> ***"We're always striving to make our resort comfortable and modern!"***
>
> or
>
> ***"Exciting new changes welcome you each time you visit our resort!"***

Comment: These smack of typical, and therefore meaningless, marketing phrases to me I'm afraid.

Comment: @DavidAldridge, typical, yes, but not meaningless. You need to read the intent into it - both my examples are basically implying that there is change (read: construction or disruption) going on at our resort.

Answer (score 2):

Use "We are updating our resort." (Or "modernizing" or "greatly improving")

Rarely are people interested that you "are working" (even *very* hard) to do something. I suspect that was what bothered you about your phrase.

A common similar problem is seen in much advertising writing that says things like, "We strive to meet your needs."

You either meet needs or you don't. "Striving" implies you have a hard time doing it.

Answer (score 1):

"Working on" is surely implied by "updating", unless you are updating the resort without doing any work.

"We are updating our resort" is direct and meaningful.

Comment: "We are updating our resort" is exactly what the OP is trying to avoid per the comment, *"I prefer not to use it as it may imply that we are under construction works and may affect our business."* (Which is why I resorted to my veiled innuendos in my answer.)